# SQL for Exclude

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which is a simple lists of ID numbers and NAMES - I am trying to write a SQL which only returns rows where the NAME does not have particular IDs.

This has been stumping me - the query below returns all as they have other IDs from the exclude lists (large range of IDs). How to structure a query where only those who don't have ID 2 or 3 are returned -- i.e. only returns 'bob' for table below.

select * from TABLE where ID not in (2, 3)

```
ID  NAMES
1   bob
1   alice
2   alice
1   dave
2   dave
3   dave
4   dave
```

Thank you.

Comment: Use language to actually clearly say what you want or how can you code it? You want rows where there does not exist a value in some set/column/group that is in some set/column/group etc. And how *exactly* are you allowed to express your input disallowed set in a query? Once you are clear this will be a faq. PS Observe that a *clear specification* is required for code questions: Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); clear specification & explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is `group by` and `having`:

```
select name
from t
group by name
having sum(case when ID in (2, 3) then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

If you want the original ids, you can add `listagg(id, ',') within group (order by id)` to the `select`.  Or use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.name = t.name and
                        t2.id in (2, 3)
                 );
```